# Apply effect on a specific CSS background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem in my HTML / JS / CSS code.

I have set 2 background images, one with a transparent component and the other that stays behind, is just a regular one.

Here's my CSS:

```
body {
  background-size:cover;
  background-color:#03F;
  background-image:url(tablietTf.png), url(road.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat, no-repeat;
}
```

I'm trying to access the image in the back (`road.jpg`) so that I can change the contrast / brightness of it when needed.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use filters (and you should, [cause they're awesome](http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/graphics/customfilters/cssfilterlab/)), **you can't**.

You have to use two separate elements, as filters affects the whole element, and not one of it's property (like background-image).

For this, create another element, make it covering all the body, and use variable filters on it afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it that way, why dont you lay it out like this. By this way you would be able to support it all the way down to ie8 and alter the images accordingly.

```
 <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            content here
        </div>
    </div>

.parent{
    background-image: url(tablietTf.png);
}
.child{
    background-image: url(road.jpg);
}
```